# How to select the biggest value from a list of duplicate entries

Tags: sql

i'm trying to query a db which contains a list of transactions. The transactions that i need must be of a specific status and if duplicate cost code are present the query should only return the ID with the highest ID number

my sample table is as follows,
Table name = foo,
status that i need is 3

```
ID       transaction date     status     cost code
1         20120101               3           5
2         20120101               3           5
3         20120101               4           7
```

in this example what i need is ID 2

Thanks

Comment: Ummmm....`select 2 as id;`  Seriously, I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @jackManey, i wish it would be that easy. but what i need is all rows with the status 3. and if duplicates are present in the cost code then the cost code with the highest ID number will be returned... sorry if i didn't make this question clearer.. and mark Paine already provided the answer that i was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from foo where status = 3 order by id desc limit 1;
```

You can replace the 3 with whichever status you're interested in retrieving.

The "order by id desc limit 1" phrase will satisfy the "ID with the highest ID number" constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAX to get the highest ID number if the selected columns are same

```
SELECT transaction_date, Status, cost_code, MAX(ID) As ID
FROM foo
GROUP BY transaction_date, Status, cost_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxID
FROM foo
WHERE status = 3
```